# Why do I need to use the @property keyword in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c

Say that I have the following public methods on my class:

```
- (BOOL)finished
{
    return _finished;
}
- (void)setFinished:(BOOL)aValue
{
    _finished = aValue;
}
```

Do I also need to set finished as a property on the class:

```
@property SomeClass *finished;
```

I may have misunderstood `@property`, but to me it seems like I am repeating myself.

- Should declare both methods and a `@property` or just one of them?

Comment: if you declare the BOOL variable as @property BOOL (nonatomic) finished;, you don't have to write the setter method to set it, you can just do [yourClass setFinished:YES];

Comment: `@property` means that you will be assigning getters and setter methods to it,  `@synthesize` actually creates them for you,  but this should now be done automatically

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By declaring a `@property`, the LLVM compiler will automatically "synthesize" your accessor methods (getter and setter), as well as an instance variable (`ivar`), denoted by an underscore prefix (`_finished`, for example)

In your case there, because you aren't doing anything special with your accessors (you are just directly reading/writing to the backing `ivar`), simply declaring a `@property` will do the trick.  You won't need to write the `-finished` and `-setFinished` methods

If you do not declare `@property`, you'll have to declare your `ivar`

`@property` also indicates you are working with a member variable of an object, and as user @Sulthan says in the comment, each class holds a list of `@properties` that can be searched

And another good point by the same user, `@property` makes your accessor methods `atomic`, which protects your `ivar` from being read while it's being written

Comment: Well, if you declare `@property` without any specifiers, the getter and setter will default to `atomic`. Also, it's not just convenience. Every class holds a list of its properties that can be searched and accessed dynamically. See `class_copyPropertyList` for example. Also, if you don't declare a property, you shouldn't be able to use dot notation (although the compiler usually allows it anyway).

Comment: Thanks for the comment, those are good points, I've edited my answer

Comment: @Sulthan The dot syntax is nothing more than short-hand for method dispatch.  It has nothing to do with `@property` other than being released in the same version of the compiler and runtime.  The only time the dot syntax can't be used is against methods that return or take `id` (or methods that don't return anything at all).

Comment: Note also that properties weren't really designed for generic introspection based programming by iterating the `class_copyPropertyList()`.   Because properties can be added by categories (not storage, though), doing this would be exceptionally fragile;  one stray category and *boom*.

Comment: And even you have to implement the accessors manually (what turns automatic ivar creation off, just btw) property gives the user of the class more semantic information than a getter and setter declaration, i. e. copy semantics and reference strength semantics.

Answer (score 2):

Even there is an accepted answer, I think some information and clarification has to be added.

A. `@property` does *not* synthesize anything. It is a method declaration. Period. This is the reason why it is allowed in protocols. (Method implementations are not allowed, not even possible in protocols.)

What let people think that is the fact, that if you do not implement alls required accessors manually, the compiler implicitly assumes a *`@synthesize`* in the *implementation* and that synthesized the accessors.

But, yes, an implicit or explicit `@synthesize` requires `@property`. (But not the other way round!)

B. Using `@property` you have to declare an ivar, too, if you explicitly define the required accessors. This is, because the implicit synthesize is "turned-off" in such a case (for good reasons).

C. Beside convenience there is a real advantage of `@property`: It adds semantic information to the property. Beside bundling getter and setter (what is the getter for `-setFinished:`? `-isFinished`? `-finished`) it holds information about copying and reference strength (`weak`, `strong`, `copy`). Atomicity is less important, because in most cases atomicity of access does not help to solve problems of concurrent execution.